# Unable to get table data from a html page

Tags: php, html, curl, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to get some data fields in a table in a html webpage. The webpage is dynamically generated on posting some content. I am using `php-curl` to get the web page and then `xpath` to get the data from some fields. I am able to get the page not the specific fields. The code looks like this

```
$url="http://www.rtu.ac.in/results/reformat.php";
$post="rollnumber=08epccs060&filename=fetchmodulesem_4_btech410m.php&button=Submit";
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$content=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$totalPath="html/body/table[4]/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]";
$page=new DOMDocument();
$xpath=new DOMXPath($page);
$page->loadHTML($content);
$page->saveHTML();  // this shows the page contents

$total=$xpath->query($totalPath);
echo $total->length;    //shows 0
echo $total->item(0)->nodeValue;   //shows nothing
```

The `xpath` is correct as I have checked it with `FirePath`. What I understand from this is that `$xpath->query` is not doing is job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You write:

```
echo $total->length;    //shows 0
```

That means that the xpath returned 0 elements. So it's actually not doing what you would like it to do.

```
//html/body/table[4]/tr[3]/td[4]
```

Or otherwise check the syntax of your xpath query that you didn't made an error.

Additionally I would first load the HTML document and then initialize the xpath object.

```
$totalPath="//html/body/table[4]/tr[3]/td[4]";
$page=new DOMDocument();
$page->loadHTML($content);
$xpath=new DOMXPath($page);    
$total=$xpath->query($totalPath);
```

Edit: Removed tbody as suggested by Wrikken.

**EDIT:**  Enable error reporting incl. warnings so you can ensure that a) the HTML is properly loaded into DomDocument and b) if there is a problem with the XPath you see it.

---

Got it to run. This is my code:

```
<?php

$url="http://www.rtu.ac.in/results/reformat.php";
$post="rollnumber=08epccs060&filename=fetchmodulesem_4_btech410m.php&button=Submit";
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$content=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo 'Size: ', strlen($content), "\n";
echo 'Beginning: ', substr($content, 0, 512), "\n\n";

$page=new DOMDocument();
$page->recover=false;
$page->loadHTML($content);

echo "\nLoaded XML:\n", $page->saveXML($page), "\n";


$xpath=new DOMXPath($page);
$totalPath="html/body/table[4]/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]";

$paths = array(
    '//body',
    '//body/table',
    '//body/table[4]',
    '//body/table[4]/tr',
    '//body/table[4]/tr[3]',
    '//body/table[4]/tr[3]/td',
    '//body/table[4]/tr[3]/td[4]',
    '//html/body/table[4]/tr[3]/td[4]',
);


foreach($paths as $path) {
    $result=$xpath->query($path);
    echo $path, ': ', $result->length, "\n";
}
```

And this is the output (cutted the top output which was for loading verification only):

```
//body: 1
//body/table: 4
//body/table[4]: 1
//body/table[4]/tr: 3
//body/table[4]/tr[3]: 1
//body/table[4]/tr[3]/td: 4
//body/table[4]/tr[3]/td[4]: 1
//html/body/table[4]/tr[3]/td[4]: 1
```

Always returns a length meaning that there is a node at least.

Comment: @hakre: `//html/body/table[4]/tr[3]/td[4]` doesnt work too. i also tried `//body/table[4]/tr[3]/td[4]` but still the same. and why the order of `loadHTML` and `xpath` initialization should make a difference?

Comment: why the order of loadHTML and xpath initialization should make a difference? - I'm not sure, but just to ensure it's not the cause of error. If I initalize xpath on an empty document, well than I can not query anything. That's the idea behind it, probably there is some optimization, but I'm not sure about this. So it could make a difference but must not. Just wanted to be helpful.

Comment: @hakre: no the order doesnt make any difference i have written code like this previously to get contents from some other sites and it worked there

Comment: @lovesh: The HTML you're trying to load does fail with DomDocument. I assume it's empty so you can't query it anyway. Better do propper error checking. I think the xpath is the wrong point to look into to find your error right now.

Comment: @hakre: the load does work here, it does throw a hell of a tantrum about improper formatted HTML, but it can recover.

Comment: @Wrikken, I got it to run w/o any problems. Made a little array to build the xpath, works like a charm.

Comment: @lovesh: see [Runtime Configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php) and [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php). Normally `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);` is good for test scripts.

Comment: Nice one (although using `/html` instead of `//html` speeds it up a little: xpath only has to search the root for a HTML node), and @lovesh: see, without `/tbody` :P

Comment: @Wrikken: Thx for the xpath hint, I just was coding downhill to find out what was going on. And yeah, no tbody, that's by firefox, I know that from webdesign, it's added while it loads the dom.

Comment: @hakre: thanks for the above. it worked but still `$total->item(0)->nodeValue` doesnt show anything.any idea why this doesnt work?

Comment: @lovesh: I get `743` for `$result->item(0)->nodeValue` (in my script, for the last two xpaths).

Comment: @hakre: i think the major change that u made to my code was adding `$page->recover=false;` what does it do?

Comment: @lovesh: It's all [in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.recover). It's an internal mode to recover errors. Actually it can be true or false, I first had it true but it makes no difference. Is in there for testing purposes, in case it would had helped with loading the document.

Comment: @hakre:i am getting 743 when i add `$result->item(0)->nodeValue,` to your for loop but when i add `echo $xpath->query($totalPath)->item(0)->nodeValue;` at the end of my code it doent work. why this happens

Comment: @lovesh: Let's do it this way: You concentrate to find out with your script and later on you tell me. I tell you then if it was the error or not. But before, give yourself a ten minute break from the computer and do something else. Good idea?

Comment: @hakre: you know i also tried using `tidy` on the html content before feeding it to `loadHTML` but it was not working. can you suggest some resources that can help me learn about such issues

Comment: @hakre: it worked i changed the `$totalPath` to include a `//` at the beginning so that it becomes `//html/body/table[4]/tr[3]/td[4]`. now i dont understand this because html is the top element of my page and is there shuld'nt be any need to append a `//` t the beginning

Comment: @lovesh: take a look into variables before you process them to validate they contain what you expect: [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) and [print_r()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) are helpful for that. Then read the warnings, often they contain important hints for the little mistakes one can make. Learning about a language is always one step at a time. Do tiny steps and gather as much information as you can from the manual.

Comment: `//` marks the root node AFAIK. But I might be wrong with that. Xpath is documented here: [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) (But it's some other sort of manual, probably more technically in it's writing, however it's pretty complete).

Comment: From the docs: "//para selects all the para descendants of the document root and thus selects all para elements in the same document as the context node".

Comment: @hakre: yeah i ve read the XPath documentation and it says that you include `//` when you are not giving the absolute path of an element but trying to get all elements of that type but as far as this case is concerned my xpath for `$totalPath` was an absolute xpath

Comment: @lovesh: Right, `//html...` and `/html...` do work. That's not the cause of the error. I assume it was because of `tbody` you had in `$totalPath`. `$totalPath="/html/body/table[4]/tr[3]/td[4]";` works for me.

Comment: @hakre:this works for me too what i tried was `html/body/table[4]/tr[3]/td[4]`. wat i am reasoning here is that `html` is the root element of the page so i should not need to append a `/` or `//`

Comment: @hakre: i commented out `$page->recover=false;` from your code and it still works and that makes your code almost identical to mine except that mine didnt work. its getting wierd

Comment: @lovesh: As I wrote earlier, that `recover` property makes no difference. You can upload your code somewhere as you have it now so I can give it a run here if it helps.

Comment: @hakre: my code worked. yesterday i hadn't saved my file and was refreshing the page in the browser.its working. sometimes i act too silly

Comment: @lovesh: Well I think every-one has such a story to tell, that's just how we work when "stressed" with problems :). For testing I suggest the commandline, because it's much faster then pressing the refresh button in the browser.

Comment: @hakre:thanks for the help. i was stuck on this for long and i observed for this particular site the order of `loadHTML` and `domxpath` mattered,though this didnt matter with some other sites. Wrikken mentioned that firefox puts a `tbody` element on its own. how can i figure out such things

Comment: @lovesh: Always check the XML data you actually received, e.g. in the shell. If you output it into the browser first, the browser needs to convert it into some DOM before display so it get's changed. If you need it bare, use plain text as in the shell. And sure a good part is to get "better" in problems, e.g. to find the strategies for one's own to come to a conclusion one can trust one-self. Less assuming where an error might be but more strictly checking where the error is not to locate the root cause. Always locate the root cause of a problem, then you learn. That's always a progress.

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at the HTML: the `/tbody` isn't there, and is just added in by Firefox. Remove that portion, and gain a healthy distrust of that tool ;)

---

**edit**:

And indeed the order should be:

```
$page=new DOMDocument();
$page->loadHTML($content);
$xpath=new DOMXPath($page);
```

As DOMXpath takes snapshots, it doesn't track DOM changes afterwards.

Comment: you mean my xpath should be like this `$totalPath="html/body/table[4]/tr[3]/td[4]";`

Comment: Yup, possibly with a `/` before `html` (been a while since I used `DOMXPath`), but yes, that's about it.

Comment: firefox doesnt insert `tbody` i have checked the html source by `firebug`'s `inspect element` and the `tbody` is there in the html. also i tried removing `tbody` from my xpath but still no change in the output. can u please run my code in your browser and check. i am using firefox 4

Comment: *sigh* It does add the `tbody`. Do NOT trust the DOM browser. Download the html, open it up in notepad. Firebug's DOM browser is what Firefox makes of it after all kinds of tweaks. Then again, there is also another problem: you should use `loadHTML` _before_ creating the `DOMXPath` (which actually uses a snapshot of that point, and doesn't know about changes in the DOM afterwards. Do that, and `/html/body/table[4]/tr[3]/td[4]` WITHOUT `/tbody` works.

Comment: Can confirm it works w/o /tbody. Added my test-script and output to my answer.